# Compilation error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems with findElement(By.Id()) using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, object, selenium-webdriver, compilation

I have configured Java, Eclipse and Selenium to be used for automating a web based application.
But, I am facing below mentioned issues:

Issue 1: Warning : Build path specifies execution environment JavaSE-14. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.

Issue 2: Unable to access objects of selenium in the code.

Issue 3: Getting the below mentioned compilation error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
The method sendKeys(String) is undefined for the type Object
The method sendKeys(String) is undefined for the type Object

Below is the code:

```
package palettepkg;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class palettelogin {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Selenium\\Drivers\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        
        InternetExplorerDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        
        driver.get("http://adclnapdev01v.bcg.com:8030");
        
        //driver.manage().window().maximize();
        
        driver.findElement(By.Id("unamebean")).sendKeys("VERMA");
        
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        
        driver.findElement(By.className(".LoginText")).sendKeys("Work@12345678");
        
        //driver.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: The method sendKeys(String) is undefined for the type Object The method sendKeys(String) is undefined for the type Object
```

...implies that the the method `sendKeys(String)` is undefined for the type Object **`By.Id`**.

As per the documentation the method is [**`By id​(java.lang.String id)`**](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html#id(java.lang.String)) not `By.Id`:

```
public static By id​(java.lang.String id)

Parameters:
id - The value of the "id" attribute to search for.

Returns:
A By which locates elements by the value of the "id" attribute.
```

---

### Solution

So effectively, your line of code will be:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("unamebean")).sendKeys("VERMA");
```

Comment: if there is no method then erro should be there is no method Id for By right ?

Answer (score 0):

```
InternetExplorerDriver driver
```

Change to

```
WebDriver driver
```

When you define driver as internetexploterdriver you are downcasting it meaning methods native to internetexplorerdriver will only be available

You have to upcast for the WebDriver interface methods to be available.

When you define WebDriver driver , both WebDriver methods and internetexplorerdriver methods will be available

Comment: Whats wrong with `InternetExplorerDriver driver`?

Comment: @DebanjanB i added the reason , it won't expose the methods avaiable in webdriver

Comment: Possibly OP's usecase doesn't needs that :)

Comment: @DebanjanB for second issue :)